# discord bot - userinfo command "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Tags: python, discord

I want to create a userinfo command but i still get a error "embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {member}")
IndentationError: unexpected indent" i dont know if thats enough to understand where my mistake is (i just started with coding)

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx, member: discord.Member):
        
        
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                        
                embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {member}")
                embed.add_field(name="ID", value=member.id)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.display_name)
                embed.add_field(name="Activity", value=member.activity)
            
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                
                embed.add_field(name="Joined at", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Created at", value=member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an IndentationError the way you formatted the code is the problem. Try this:

```
embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                    
embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {member}")
embed.add_field(name="ID", value=member.id)
embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.display_name)
embed.add_field(name="Activity", value=member.activity)
        
embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            
embed.add_field(name="Joined at", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Created at", value=member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Hope this may be of help.

Comment: now i get this error "embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at) ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: There is probably another indentation error above your embed code

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the indentation spaces and then manually hit the spacebar 2 or 4 times, or you could delete all the spaces before the code and then hit the tab on all of the lines, you could try to do `F8` on VSC.

An alternative way is to do it on your IDE, if you're using something like Visual Studio Code, you can do `Tab + Shift + P` and search `Convert Indentation to Tabs`, or you could choose `Reindent Lines` in the search bar.